# Is the DFT really the DTFS?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fast-fourier-transform

In the continuous domain, I know that the Fourier Series is given by:
$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ke^{j\frac{2\pi}{T}kt}$$
So in the discrete domain, it would make sense that a discrete N-periodic signal could be represented with the 'Discrete Time Fourier Series' (I assume) as:
$$x[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$$
However, my book says that a discrete periodic signal 'is completely described' as:
$$x[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$$
because of the inherent periodicity of discrete complex exponentials. Is the DFT (and DFS) then technically just ***one*** period of the DTFS? And are the technical limits of summation of the DTFS $(-\infty,\infty)$?

And if so, doesn't dropping all those terms from the summation technically cause the equality not to be true anymore, i.e.
$$x[n]\neq\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$$
since $x[n]$ needs the sum of ***all*** harmonic complex exponentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we're talking discrete time, so I'll be using $N$ for the period of our function rather than $T$.

In fact, we do have exact equality:
$$
x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi kn}{N}}
$$
where $X_k = \frac 1{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2 \pi}N kn}$.  The easiest way to see this intuitively is with a little bit of linear algebra.

Let $\tilde x[n]$ denote the function $\tilde x[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi kn}{N}}$, which I attempt to prove is equal to $x[n]$ (for all $n$).  Since both $x$ and $\tilde x$ are $N$-periodic, it is enough to know that $x[n] = \tilde x[n]$ for $n = 0,1,2,\dots, N-1$.  In other words, we're going to think of $x[n]$ as really being the vector $\mathbf x = (x[0],x[1],\dots,x[N-1]) \in \Bbb C^N$.

Let $b_k[n] = e^{j \frac{2 \pi k n}{N}}$.  The values of $b_k[n]$ for $0 \leq n \leq N-1$ form a vector of $N$ entries.  The question is this: can we find $X_k$ such that $X_0b_0[n] + \cdots + X_{N-1} b_{N-1}[n]$ is exactly the same as the function $x[n]$?   In terms of vectors: if we define $\mathbf b_k = (e^{j \frac{2 \pi k (0)}{N}}, \dots, e^{j \frac{2 \pi k (N-1)}{N}})$, can we find coefficients $X_k$ so that 
$$
X_0 \mathbf b_0 + \cdots + X_{N-1} \mathbf b_{N-1} = \mathbf x
$$
Or as a system of equations, we have
$$
X_0 b_0[0] + \cdots + X_{N-1}b_{N-1}[0] = x[0]\\
X_0 b_0[1] + \cdots + X_{N-1}b_{N-1}[1] = x[1]\\
\vdots \\
X_0 b_0[N-1] + \cdots + X_{N-1}b_{N-1}[N-1] = x[N-1]
$$
As it turns out, this is a linear system of $N$ equations on $N$ variables (the variables $X_0,X_1,\dots,X_{N-1}$) that we can completely solve!

To put it another way: because the vectors $\mathbf b_0,\dots,\mathbf b_{N-1}$ form a *basis* of the $N$-dimensional space $\Bbb C^N$, every vector $\mathbf x \in \Bbb C^N$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of them.  Because the functions $b_0[n],\dots,b_{N-1}[n]$ form a *basis* of the $N$-dimensional space of $N$-periodic functions, every $N$-periodic function $x[n]$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of them.

If we were to write out this system of equations with a matrix, we would have $W \mathbf X = \mathbf x$ where $\mathbf X = (X_0,\dots,X_{N-1})$, $\mathbf x$ is as before, and $W$ is (a multiple of) the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), as described in the link.

---

Another perspective: it turns out that there is a certain "aliasing" among the other complex exponentials that makes them very obviously redundant.  For example, with $k = N$, we find
$$
b_N[n] = e^{j \frac{2 \pi N n}{N}} = e^{j 2 \pi n} = [e^{j 2 \pi}]^n = 1\\
b_{N+1}[n] = e^{j \frac{2 \pi (N+1)n}N} = e^{j \frac{2 \pi Nn}N} \cdot e^{j \frac{2 \pi 1n}{N} } = 
1 \cdot b_1[n] = b_1[n]
$$
and so on so that in general, we have $b_{k + mN}[n] = b_k[n]$ for any integer $m$.

Comment: But if $x[n]$ really equals $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$, then how is it possible that $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$? Even given that $b_{k+mN}[n]=b_{k}[n]$?

Comment: It's not possible, since your $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty$ is not equal to $x[n]$. When going from the continuous FS to the DFT, it is *not* correct to simply change the $t$'s into $n$'s and the sums into integrals, however intuitive that may seem. Because of how they're defined, the $X_k$s from the DFT have a different kind of meaning from the $X_k$s in the continuous FS.

Comment: In fact, your infinite sum doesn't even converge.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, so just to be clear, above you've shown that an arbitrary N-periodic function $x[n]$ equals $\tilde{x}[n]$, which in turn equals the ***finite*** sum $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X_k e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$?

Comment: Yes, basically. I haven't proven that the $X_k$s are given by the usual formula, but I've argued that suitable $X_k$s must exist.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still confused as to how an arbitrary N-periodic function with $n\in\mathrm{Z}$ can (intuitively) be represented with a finite number of complex exponentials-- is this because there are only N frequencies below the fundamental frequency $\frac{2\pi}{N}$, and therefore $x[n]$ can only consist of a sum of those N periodic functions, in this case the complex exponentials?

Comment: The perspective I prefer is that the space of $N$-periodic (discrete) functions is a finite-dimensional vector space (and this is not true for $T$-periodic continuous functions).  If you really want to break it down in terms of frequencies: remember, we're breaking a function with frequency $f_0$ into a sum of components with frequencies *higher* than the fundamental frequencies (specifically, the integer multiples of $f_0$, i.e. the "overtones").  The real idea is that, since we're looking at discrete time, there are only $N$ *distinguishible* such frequencies, I guess.

Comment: You might eventually relate this idea to that of the [Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).  By sampling instead of taking continuous input, you lose the information from the higher overtones and everything collapses into the finitely many $X_k$.

Comment: Awesome, that helps very much.

Comment: Does your derivation of the DFT above for vectors $\mathbf{x}$ in the $N$-dimensional space $\Bbb C^N$ extend to the $N$-dimensional space of $N$-periodic functions, say $M$, because the two spaces are isomorphic, $\Bbb C^N\sim M$? Or at least, is that one explanation/argument?

Comment: That’s right. More specifically, the map $\phi: M\to \Bbb C^n$ defined by $\phi(x[n]) = \mathbf x$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.